# Peak-calling using homer

Tags: shell, atac-seq, peak-calling

I have a total of 78 ATAC seq samples from which Im trying to do a peak call .I tried this `batchParallel.pl findPeaks peaks` function but i couldn't find the output what it makes.

So I tried using loop but again the peak file is not written due to incorrect argument usage I guess.

These are my sample directories where i have all the tags

```
SRR2920564  SRR2920565
```

I used homer to make tag directories and now i using it for peakcalling.

here is my command.

```
for d in */ ; do findPeaks $d -style factor -o "${d}.txt" ; done
```

What i need is all the peakfile should be written as the directory name.

Such as if directory is "`SRR2920564`" then my peak file should be written in the same directory as `SRR2920564.txt`

I do run the loop it runs successfully but no output written. May be a mundane mistake am not able to figure it out.

Any suggestion or help would be highly appreciated .

Comment: Your output file is a bit weird.
*findPeaks directoryname/ -style factor -o directoryname/.txt*

You would be attempting to create a file called ".txt" inside each directory? (Also do you need those quotes).

Did you try running this with "-o auto" and checking in each directory if the corresponding files (i.e peaks.txt, regions.txt, transcripts.txt, etc..) were generated?

Comment: I tried running auto it gives an output peak.txt but when it would be easy if i can name them as the directory name for as unique name for each file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to strip the `/` from `$d`, for which there are a number of options:

```
for d in */ ; do 
    dname=`basename $d`
    findPeaks $d -style factor -o ${dname}.txt
done
```

or

```
for d in */ ; do
    dname=${d%%/}
    findPeaks $d -style factor -o ${dname}.txt
done
```

There are likely other ways one could go about this. Having said that, since you're not running these in parallel you could simply move the default output file (`peak.txt`) to a file name of your choice (using one of the strategies above).